# Angular stateprovider always hits 'otherwise' state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to set the state through a controller while parsing 1 parameter.
From what I can gather, the preferred state is called, however the "otherwise" state is loaded immediately afterwards.
I discovered that preferred state was being called by hitting the back button. 
When the back button is clicked, the preferred state was called.
Seems like a small issue in my stateprovider settings but I simply can't manage to find it.

Below is part of my controller.js file.

```
.controller('resultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'searchfactory', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, searchfactory, $state) {
    $scope.results = searchfactory.getresults();
    console.log($scope.results);
    $scope.showdoc = function(docid){
        console.log(docid);
        $state.go('doctor', { docid: docid });
    }
}])

.controller('doctorCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    alert($stateParams.docid);

}])
```

Below is my routes file handling the "doctor" part.

```
.state('doctor', {
    url: '/doctor/{docid}',
    templateUrl: 'templates/doctor.html',
    controller: 'doctorCtrl'
  })
```

Upon hitting the back button, the url is shown as http://192.168.8.100:8100/#/doctor/11 which I think is the proper url.
Also, the alert pops up as well. the redirection is done after the "ok" button is clicked on the alert.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does `templates/doctor.html` exist??

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Hi. Yes it  does

Comment: Also not sure if it helps. But when I go to the http://192.168.8.100:8100/#/doctor/11 url and refresh it stays there. Doesn't get redirected

Comment: check if you are using `href` in view.

Comment: I knew there was something fishy when u said href. Turns out I had href="#" and the ng-click which made the redirection. It works now.  Thank you so much

Comment: can I post this in answer. Will you accept it??

Comment: Yeah sure. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `templates/doctor.html exist` or there is `href` their.